# Doubts in the $k -$tuple of primes $\mathcal{H}=\{0,2,6,12,20,26,30,32\}$

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

While studying some $k-$tuples of primes I found the following $\mathcal{H}=\{0,2,6,12,20,26,30,32\}$ which seems admissible to me.

using the primes package in Rstudio I get the following $p_1$ between $1$ and $100000000$ :

$348431, 26074901, 32624981, 43713557, 51877097, 64981067, 67787537, 73184621, 74904101, 80372681$

$p_1$ primes appear such that $p_1\equiv 1\pmod{10}$ and $p_1\equiv 7\pmod{10}$

According to my calculations, each $p_1\equiv 1\pmod{10}$ should be $348431\pmod{3484470}$.

and each $p_1\equiv 7\pmod{10}$ should be $43713557\pmod{437135730}$.

I see that they are not in the arithmetic progression $3484470n+348431$ or $437135730n+43713557$.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, in what arithmetic progression can I "put" these primes?

(I must add that it seems strange to me that this sequence of primes does not appear in OEIS, this makes me more doubtful about it)

Comment: $k=41$ works. $(41, 43, 47, 53, 61, 67, 71, 73)$

Comment: I guess to be more specific: $k = 41+105n$ works. Because the sequence only has a length of $32$, we needn't worry about missing numbers divisible by $11$ or $13$, because they can be put into the middle of the span wherever, and the tuple won't hit two of them. I suppose we could be more rigorous, but admissible just means it's not destroyed by residues of small primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This collection is not admissable since we can add $8$ into the list and still have a collection (probably) giving infinite many prime tuples.

The smallest number (after $11$) giving a prime-tuple is $$29597411$$ Every such number must be of the form $210k+11$. Not sure whether we can insert further even numbers without destroying this property.